# Load Wordpress post in Bootstrap Modal with post ID

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I can not solve this problem.
I need to load an externally post within a Bootstrap Modal. Using just the post id.
It´s a One Web Page, so all the posts load in the index, and don´t display individually.

I use this [example](http://pulse.sg/posts/bootstrap-3-remote-url-modal)

and it is working properly just hanging 'ID' by GET.
This link: 
'href='/cargarnota.php?ids=' call the external file correctly.

But when in the 'cargarnota.php' file I add the loop or query, the modal stops working.

### This is cargarnota.php file:

```
<?php
$parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );
?>

<?php
$Id = $_GET['ids'];


$content_post = get_post($Id);
$title = $content_post->post_title;
$content = $content_post->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
$enlace = post_permalink( $Id );
?>


<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><b><i class="indicator flaticon-close33"></i></b></button>
    <p class="enviar-nota">Enviar nota</p>
    <?php echo '<h4 class="verde">' . $title . '</h4>'; ?>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">    
    <?php 
echo $content;
echo post_permalink( $Id ); 
    ?>

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

---

That code not work and the modal don´t display.

### But this one work correctly:

```
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Enviar nota</h4>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">

<?php 
$id = $_GET['ids'];
echo $id;
?>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

---

This code displays the modal and the ID in it.

Someone knows how to get it work.?

Comment: you need 1 dummy modal on your page, the real modals with content can load using the remote attribute and passing your id as you showed with `href='/cargarnota.php?ids=`.  The example you showed is correct is saying that you need this js on your page, `$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () { $(this).removeData('bs.modal'); });` that needs to be there to load the new content into the modal using multiple modals.  (which btw is going away in BS4.0)  So your example seems kind of incomplete, you'd have a loop to make your buttons and another page to just load each modal's content

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you indicate me.
Tenes an example or a website with a more detailed explanation. I tried using jquery, but I got it working.

Comment: You link to an example in your question.  They do it right, check out the spot where it says "Link to Remote Modal, you can also pass in variables".    You didn't follow that tutorial, just go back and pay more attention to what they do

Comment: what do you mean when you say the "modal stops working" ?  does that mean that the content doesn't load in the modal, or that the bs modal doesn't launch at all, or something else?

Comment: I mean that the bs modal doesn´t launch at all,.. The background goes black, but don´t load the remote file. Here´s the example www.saviacomunicacion.com.ar/test2014/  , scroll to SALA DE PRENSA, open the first one, click in Compartir and then click in the mail icon. Thanks for your time.

Comment: you're using jquery in no conflict mode.  You pasted in some jquery code using the usual $() selector, but in your case because of the way you've configured your theme and jquery, you need to replace that with j() so update your modal destroy to be `j('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () { j(this).removeData('bs.modal'); });` and then it might work

Comment: I tried what you say, but still not working. The problem is that when I put the WP loop in the remote file (cargarnota.php) the Modal stop loading the file. The JS works, but there nothing to show, because it not load the content, which is in the remote file.

Comment: the question made it seem like you were having trouble with your modal.  just plop something above your query so it returns something and you can eliminate that issue.  Then you just have to fix your query, which is probably an easy question if you pose it alone without the modal non-issue confusing things

Comment: Thanks for your time. I still trying to make it work.

Comment: I found this http://tutsme-webdesign.info/bootstrap-3-1-and-modals-with-remote-content/ and in a coment said "**it’s possible to use a PHP file as a remote file. ... probably won’t work because it’ll require execution of PHP commands after the modal has loaded.** " I think that is the problem why i can't make it work.

Comment: It works very nicely, I happen to be using it right now, passing an id to load order details in each modal for an admin area.  Very similar to what you're doing with posts.  There are 2 parts to this...the frontend piece which bootstrap does for you, and then just loading the remote file.  You can test it by using a static remote file just to make sure that the frontend will work fine.  Then you just need to make a dynamic remote file and call it with your ids, and have your query load the right post for that id.  It seems like you've done that with cargarnota.php?id=xx  so directly test that

Comment: Yes, I test with a static file and works perfectly, the example is in the question. But when a tried to ad the query from WP, to load the post, it stops working, and don´t know why,. i´m very confused with this,..

Comment: does your file with the query have `include "wp-load.php"` in it with a correct path to wp-load.php?  Including that file will load all of the core wordpress functionality, without it your query won't work. Also, temporarily put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your file so that you can see error output.

Comment: Thank you very much, thats work correctly. Thousand thanks

Comment: **cargarnota.php** was edited in the question to represent the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

The cargarnota.php file was missing `include "wp-load.php";` so the wordpress functions were not loading, therefore get_post wasn't printing the post content to the screen.  Since the remote content wasn't loading, the modal failed.

The poster has now modified the question to include wp-load.php, and this seems to have fixed the problem with the original code.